# NodeJS TypeError "X is not a function"?

Tags: node.js

I am developing a Facebook Messenger bot in node.js as part of an online course I am doing.  I've been following the lectures and I have made changes to my code as instructed.  However everything has stopped working!  I check my Heroku logs for errors (I'm hosting the app through heroku) and I get the following error:

```
2017-10-25T09:29:15.604572+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: userData is not a function
2017-10-25T09:29:15.604574+00:00 app[web.1]:     at setSessionAndUser (/app/app.js:1089:6)
2017-10-25T09:29:15.604575+00:00 app[web.1]:     at receivedPostback (/app/app.js:902:5)
2017-10-25T09:29:15.604575+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/app.js:125:6
2017-10-25T09:29:15.604576+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Array.forEach (native)
2017-10-25T09:29:15.604577+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Array.forEach (native)
2017-10-25T09:29:15.604578+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/app.js:112:14
2017-10-25T09:29:15.604577+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/app.js:117:24
2017-10-25T09:29:15.604579+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
2017-10-25T09:29:15.604580+00:00 app[web.1]:     at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
2017-10-25T09:29:15.604581+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Route.dispatch (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
```

What does `userData is not a function` mean?

In my code, userData appears in a function called setSessionAndUser, which is used to add the session ID to a user map.  The function looks like this:

```
function setSessionAndUser(senderID) {
    if (!sessionIds.has(senderID)) {
        sessionIds.set(senderID, uuid.v1());
    }

    if (!usersMap.has(senderID)) {
        userData( function (user) {
        usersMap.set(senderID, user);
        }, senderID);
    }
}
```

If you need to see my code in full I have it here:

https://gist.github.com/SamuelHolmes82/e6d577b4ce3d7768e6555fd22e102565

Comment: under userData which function you want to call

Comment: userData.function_name(function (user) {   replace the function_name with your function name

Comment: OK, that worked!  THANK YOU!

Can you add the above to this question as an answer so I can mark it as best answer?

Comment: just want to know which function you have added

Comment: I changed it to read "userData.addUser( function (user) .... etc.